# Counting nodes/vertices in large polyline GeoJSON?

Tags: qgis, python, line, vertices

I have a large .geojson file (~ 1 GB) of made up of thousands of polylines.  My objective is to count the number of vertices (not end points) in the entire file.  Is there a python module that is suited for this type of analysis?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Can we use R rather than Python? ;)

Comment: yes of course, R may even be preferable

Comment: Are you open to using a module that is tied to an open source GIS app like pyQGIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **json** or **simplejson** library to convert the geojson to a Python object, then loop through each LineString. For each LineString get the length of the coordinates list, subtract 2 for the end points, and add it to a running sum.

Or use the [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) json processor:

```
cat my.geojson | jq "[.geometries[].coordinates | length-2]  | add"
```

assuming you have a FeatureCollection of LineStrings, you may need to tweak for your actual geometry.

Comment: I've tried this command but I receive the error `jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

Comment: I misread your original question. Updated the JQ filter query, but I'm guessing without an example of your GeoJSON data.

Comment: Still getting an error `Alexanders-MacBook-Pro:Pune alexander$ cat routes.geojson| jq '[.geometries[].coordinates| length -2] add'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.geometries[].coordinates| length -2] add                                       
jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: Since it says `Unix shell quoting issues?` you probably need the query in double quotes.

Comment: In my case `cat my.geojson | jq "[.features[].geometry.coordinates[] | length-2] | add"` worked like a charm.