# Counting nodes and edges in road network

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, network, nodes

I have a road network `'TR_ROAD'` with EPSG:4283 crs and 1219 features. Based on geospatial theory, the road network is combination of `nodes` and `edges`.

1. I am trying to count the number of nodes and edges in a network.
2. Also, the I am trying to calulate the number of nodes connected to specific street/road as shown in image 2.

**What I tried:** Searched for exisiting answers ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198756/counting-nodes-vertices-in-large-polyline-geojson), [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403646/seeing-which-node-has-given-node-id-in-osmnx)) but couldn,t found the relevant
solution.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Count the number of nodes

*Count no. of edges see below*

1. [Extract the vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) of your lines - you get a point layer `Vertices`. Run [delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries).
2. [Explode the lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) - you get a line layer `Exploded`.
3. On the `Vertices` layer, create a new Boolean field with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and this expression - it return `1` (`true`) for nodes, `0` (`false`) for all other vertices. The expression evaluates if 3 or more (>2) lines from the layer `Exploded` touch the current point: in this case, it is a node, otherwise just a simple vertex. If you also want to include end-points of lines (dangles), simply change `>2` to `<>2`, then also points that touch just one line will be included:

   ```
    if (
        array_length (
            overlay_touches( 
                'Exploded', 
                buffer ($geometry,1)
            )
        )>2,
        1,
        0
    )
   ```
4. If you enclose the expression in a [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#sum) statement, you get the number of nodes - 9 in the example from the screenshot below.

*Screenshot: The label (0/1) is created dynamically with the expression above:*

[image]

## Count no. of edges

This is based on the steps above:

1. [Create a new, empty multiline layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-new-vector-layers) called `network`. Copy/paste all features from the Layer `Exploded` to this layer, [select](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-features) and [merge](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#merge-selected-features) all lines. So the whole network (all lines) consist of only one multipart feature.
2. Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) to select all those features from the field created in step 3 above with value=`1`: thus get all nodes. Copy these nodes and paste them to a new point layer called `only_nodes`.
3. Split the layer `network` with the layer `only_nodes`. To split a line with points, use [SAGA's "Split Lines at Points"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264773/88814) or [the solution here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/413121/88814).
4. Based on the data and method you use, you might have to see if you don't get duplicate geometries or lines with a length of `0`. Delete these and then the number of features you have in the layer corresponds to the no. of edges. You can also calculate this number using [`count($id)`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#count).

*This is the result: 17 edges, styled in different colors:*

[image]